# How big teams work with database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unit-testing, design-patterns

Lets say I have a team, 20 developers. And we are making a project on .net. In team every one can easy create their tables according to their modules working on it.

And we think to use an ORM, can you tell me how can and which ORM tools for good to working with team. Is there any proven way?

I m asking becouse I never work with a team, so I dont know the best practices.

So you guys what kind of pattern you use?. I realy wonder.

The team members can write their unit tests and supply necessary design patterns. What kind of approach I need to create to manage team? What kind of ORM tools that we have to use?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible options is to go with Entity Framework Code First Migrations. You can look into detailed explanation on the following link:

[MSDN : Code First Migrations in Team Environments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501)

Comment: You should always use database first - your data-structures are way more important than your code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the kind of answer you are looking for.

Talk to the team. Let them decide the ORM tool they want to use, since they are the once who will use it. Just consider the tool they picked the best one for this project. I would use the same approach with method and patterns. As a manager you can provide them with the technical and non-technical specifications for the project.

Comment: I talk with them, they said they just look for salary :)

Comment: Then you got a bigger problem then just choosing the "best" ORM tool! ;-)